# Java unable to act as client for service

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, jdeveloper

So I have created a service on JDeveloper with socket adapter where a message is read from. I have followed the steps mentioned in the following link for that: https://shrikworld.blogspot.com/2014/11/demystifying-oracle-socket-adapter.html
However the problem is that when i create the java class to test the service, i get an error.

I have been trying to figure out what the issue is but i cant find anything useful on this. Here is a description of the SocketAdapter in my weblogic console:

```
Host: localhost
KeepAlive: true
EnableSDP: false
backlogQueue: 0
port: 12110
SSLEnable: false
NeedClientAuthentication: false
Timeout: 1000
```

Here is my java class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket;
            final String HOST = "localhost";
            final int PORT = 12110;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println(">>>");
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
                System.out.println(">>>");
                throw ioe;
            }
            System.out.println("sending data: EmpDetails;");
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] b = "fn111111ln111111232007-01-01100\nfn211111ln211111232007-11-01200\nfn311111ln311111232007-12-01300".getBytes();
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                os.write(b[i]);
            }
            os.flush();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            System.out.println("receiving data");
            BufferedReader soc_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String successCode = soc_in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Success Code: " + successCode);
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the error I get when I try running the code:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at SocketAdapter.Client.main(Client.java:18)
```

Comment: IPv4 vs. IPv6 issue?

Comment: @MrTux What do u mean? Sorry im really new to JDeveloper and creating services.. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: It might be possible that your server is running IPv4 only and that your client tries to connect to connect using IPv6 only.

Comment: @MrTux How do I check whether my server is running on IPv4 and client connecting on IPv6?

Answer (score -2):

Instead of taking HOST as a static string,

```
socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)
```

try taking it dynamically using,

```
socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), PORT);
```

The above should give local/private network IP address as host.